# Apache Helix run-helix-controller.sh command gives error

Tags: helix

I have installed apache Helix 1.0.0 version. I am able to setup a cluster and add resources. 
But when i try to start run-helix-controller.sh it gives below error.

Here is command  : **./run-helix-controller.sh --zkSvr localhost:2181 --cluster jbpm-cluster**

**ERROR**
[2020-05-20 06:22:29,773] [INFO ] [main] [org.apache.helix.controller.HelixControllerMain:208] - Cluster manager started, zkServer: lpwaidqu02:2181, clusterName:jbpm-cluster, controllerName:null, mode:STANDALONE
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Rebalancer**
        at org.apache.helix.InstanceType.(InstanceType.java:39)
        at org.apache.helix.controller.HelixControllerMain.startHelixController(HelixControllerMain.java:156)
        at org.apache.helix.controller.HelixControllerMain.main(HelixControllerMain.java:212)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the steps in this guide?
http://helix.apache.org/0.9.7-docs/Quickstart.html

Seems like there are a few steps (like "add cluster") before `./run-helix-controller.sh` command.